# mariadbd 10.5.18 seems to stop working

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu, galera, mariadb-10.5

I've got a three node galera cluster (mariadb 10.5.18, ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS) with a haproxy as loadbalancer in front of it.

Normally, there are

- up to 80 tcp based connection from a java application,
- two tcp connections to the galera neighbours for replication on port 4567,
- one connection to the socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
- bindings from mariadbd process for port 3306 and port 4567

The OS has 6gb ram and runs in a vm hosted on nvme devices.
In the file /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/override.conf I set a huge amount for file descriptors

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=1048576
```

and this seems to be working well:

```
/proc/`pidof mariadbd`/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             23411                23411                processes 
Max open files            1048576              1048576              files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       23411                23411                signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

And innodb_buffer_pool_size is set to 4G.

Now the process works well for an irregular period of time.
After that, connections die and the services does not seem to be available anymore.

In mysqld error log (loglevel 9) the tcp connections (~80) are closed with the message

```
2022-12-11 19:32:26 727 [Warning] Aborted connection 727 to db: 'app_db' user: 'app_user' host: 'haproxy instance' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
```

The are no messages like "Too many connections" or "Too many open files" in the error logfile.The messages about the aborted connections are the last entries in the logfile.
Beside that, no connections via socket are possible.
Top shows a relaxed system, no load, no iowait that would slow down mariadbd.

This situation last until I kill the mariadb instance with kill -9. Unfortunately other methods do not work to stop the database.
The error currently occurs only on one a those mariadb/galera nodes at the same time. Never had two instances at the same time stopping their services.

Any hint, what I might inspect next or what might be set wrong to cause my database to stop working?

Thx in advance

Comment: Is any Swap configured?  What errors in the various logs?  Can "root" connect to mariadb in order to do `SHOW PROCESSLIST`?  Lower buffer_pool to 3G as a _possible_ "cure".

Comment: swap is configured to 4gb. But it's not used during db outage. And under normal conditions, root can connect to mariadb and perform a "show processlist;"
Syslog looks good. No cronjobs are triggered before or during db outage.